# Potential performance issue on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like I am encountering a performance problem on the folowing SQL query:

```
SELECT g.Guid AS GroupGuid, Max(TimeStamp) AS LastProcessed
FROM Information 
INNER JOIN  GroupStepResults gsr ON Information.InformationId = gsr.InformationId
INNER JOIN TaskHistories th on th.TaskHistoryId=gsr.TaskHistoryId
INNER JOIN Groups g on g.GroupId=gsr.GroupId
WHERE th.Type=0
GROUP BY g.Guid;
```

This leads to the following [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkfAe0-mK):
[image: Execution plan]

My queried tables are structured as follows (database contains other tables, that are not queried here):

[image: DB Scheme]

Here is the table creations scripts:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups](
    [GroupId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Groups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GroupId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[GroupStepResults]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults](
    [InformationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskHistoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ElapsedSeconds] [float] NOT NULL,
    [IsLastResult] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorId] [int] NULL,
    [StepId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.GroupStepResults] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InformationId] ASC,
    [GroupId] ASC,
    [TaskHistoryId] ASC,
    [StepId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Information]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Information](
    [InformationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModelVersion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [WideVersion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Information] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InformationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TaskHistories]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskHistories](
    [TaskHistoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Creator] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TaskHistories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TaskHistoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Guid]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Guid] ON [dbo].[Groups]
(
    [Guid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_ErrorId]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ErrorId] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [ErrorId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_GroupId]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GroupId] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [GroupId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_InformationId]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_InformationId] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [InformationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_StepId]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_StepId] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [StepId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_TaskHistoryId]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TaskHistoryId] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [TaskHistoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [NonClusteredIndex-20210916-164346]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20210916-164346] ON [dbo].[GroupStepResults]
(
    [InformationId] ASC,
    [GroupId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Information_TimeStamp]    Script Date: 17/09/2021 11:58:29 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Information_TimeStamp] ON [dbo].[Information]
(
    [TimeStamp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ElapsedSeconds]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsLastResult]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Errors_ErrorId] FOREIGN KEY([ErrorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Errors] ([ErrorId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Errors_ErrorId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Groups_GroupId] FOREIGN KEY([GroupId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([GroupId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Groups_GroupId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Information_InformationId] FOREIGN KEY([InformationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Information] ([InformationId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Information_InformationId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Steps_StepId] FOREIGN KEY([StepId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Steps] ([StepId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.Steps_StepId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.TaskHistories_TaskHistoryId] FOREIGN KEY([TaskHistoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TaskHistories] ([TaskHistoryId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GroupStepResults] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.GroupStepResults_dbo.TaskHistories_TaskHistoryId]
GO
```

GroupStepResults contains about 7M rows, TaskHistories about 200, Informations about 70k and Groups about 1k. The query takes about 5s, which seems quite a lot. Are my expectations too high?

Comment: In addition to the graphical plan can you include the actual plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan), and also include the existing tables' indexes. Possibly you could benefit from additional index on Information and GroupSetpResults, this table is responsible for about 70% of the execution time.

Comment: I just did, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Your query performance is actually not fully benefitting from parallel execution, the most expensive operation on table GroupStepResults has 15 threads doing nothing, all the work is on a single thread. It looks like your `cost threshold for parallelism` setting is at its default of 5, it's recommended to set this higher. Try using `option(maxdop 1)` and see how this performs.

Comment: No real change with that: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJJ0aCZ7K

Comment: It would be useful to see the tables' indexes. The images you added are of no help. Add the infomation as `create index` scripted statements.

Comment: I updated the post with table creations scripts, including indexes. Sorry if that's overkill, if it is, let me know, I will clean it up.
I did nnot mention that the database contains other tables, not relevent to this query, so I guess it does not make a difference here?

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing needs improvement. I would expect the foloowing indexes for this query

```
Information (InformationId) INLUDE (TimeStamp) -- clustered index already covers this
```

```
Groups (Guid, GroupId)
```

```
GroupStepResults (GroupId, TaskHistoryId) INCLUDE (InformationId)
-- alteratively
GroupStepResults (GroupId, InformationId) INCLUDE (TaskHistoryId)
```

```
TaskHistory ([Type], TaskHistoryId)
```

You can obviously add any other `INCLUDE` columns, but keep the key columns the same

---

Note that single-column indexes are generally useless, and should be removed. You ideally want an index that starts with the `WHERE` columns as keys, continues with the `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` columns, and has the `SELECT` columns in the `INCLUDE`.

For further help see [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out, that sounds interesting. Table GroupStepResults does however not contain a `Type` column so the third index cannot contain it. But I get the idea

Comment: I created the indexes as suggested by @SQLpro, which go in the same direction, and posted the updated execution plan

Comment: Righto, sorry misread, fixed now

Comment: Combination of new indexes and rewrite of the query to prefilter better before the max on Timestamp helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to create those four indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX X1 ON TaskHistories (type, TaskHistoryId);
CREATE INDEX X2 ON Information   (InformationId, TimeStamp);
CREATE INDEX X3 ON GroupStepResults (InformationId, TaskHistoryId) INCLUDE (GroupId)
CREATE INDEX X4 ON Groups (GroupId, Guid);
```

Comment: Here is the updated execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJqYyeGmF. I don't see X3 being used

Comment: I'd say put `Timestamp` in the `INCLUDE`, I don't see why it needs to be a key column.

Comment: InformationId is the primary key of the table, as it is linked to other tables in the database. I created a new index, but that does ot seem to help (as it is not used for the queries)

Comment: I created the index you suggested, here is the [updated plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkWTTBwmt). I also removed the index on TaskHistoryId only. The performances of the query seem worse now...

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this below two query. For first one use subquery for retrieving small data sets form large volume of data with type = 0.

```
SELECT g.Guid GroupGuid
     , Max(if.TimeStamp) LastProcessed
FROM (SELECT gsr.InformationId
           , gsr.GroupId
      FROM TaskHistories th
      INNER JOIN GroupStepResults gsr
              ON th.TaskHistoryId = gsr.TaskHistoryId 
             AND th.Type = 0) t
INNER JOIN Information if
        ON if.InformationId = t.InformationId
INNER JOIN Groups g
        ON g.GroupId = t.GroupId
GROUP BY g.Guid
```

Just table ordering change for 2nd one

```
SELECT g.Guid AS GroupGuid
     , Max(if.TimeStamp) AS LastProcessed
FROM TaskHistories th
INNER JOIN GroupStepResults gsr
        ON th.TaskHistoryId = gsr.TaskHistoryId 
       AND th.Type = 0
INNER JOIN Information if
        ON if.InformationId = gsr.InformationId
INNER JOIN Groups g
        ON g.GroupId = gsr.GroupId
GROUP BY g.Guid
```

Please create an index for type and also for gsr.TaskHistoryId because gsr table have composite primary key.

Comment: Result for query 1: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJTOJ1G7t ; Result for query 2: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HydoJ1MmK . If any change, results are a bit worse (but not sure it is significant. There is already a non-clustered index on gsr.TaskHistoryId (actually used for an index seek)

Comment: @HuguesStefanski any improvement do u get?

Comment: No performance improvements

Comment: Unlikely to improve things, as the compiler can freely convert between each of these formats anyway. needs better indexing

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your query plan, the following issues may cause a performance problem.

- In the first Index Seek operator only one thread performs all read operations because the task histories table returns only one row
  [image]

You can check the [SQL Server threads - one does all the work, the other MAXDOP - 1 (5..30) do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319817/sql-server-threads-one-does-all-the-work-the-other-maxdop-1-5-30-do-noth) question for more information about this issue. Maybe you can try to force join type MERGE or HASH join.

- Another point I have noticed is that the IX_HistoryId takes lots of modification and the sampling percent is very low.

[image]

I think this issue causes a difference between the estimated and actual number of rows.

[image]

Comment: Tahnks for the info, I will read further on parallelism and see if I can do something in that area. Is there anything I can do regarding the sampling percent? I have no idea what it is or what it does (this shows how not a DBA I am :D )

Comment: Parallelism: In my thought, it is very difficult to do something in your case because your History table returns only one row.  You can see this "https://www.sqlshack.com/parallel-nested-loop-joins-the-inner-side-of-nested-loop-joins-and-residual-predicates/" article. At this point, you can add a join hint or change the join order. Statistics: You can update statistics or rebuilt the index but try this option in non-peak times because these operation can lock the table.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll read the article you linked and come back to you if any further question